# mutiple wall posting site script . have error with not display fanpage list

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token, facebook-app-requests

```
$queries = array(
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/pages'),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/groups'),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/friends'),
    );

// POST your queries to the batch endpoint on the graph.
try{
    $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
}catch(Exception $o){
    error_log($o);
}

//Return values are indexed in order of the original array, content is in ['body'] as a JSON
//string. Decode for use as a PHP array.
$user_info  = json_decode($batchResponse[0]['body'], TRUE);
$pages      = json_decode($batchResponse[1]['body'], TRUE);
$groups     = json_decode($batchResponse[2]['body'], TRUE);
$friends_list= json_decode($batchResponse[3]['body'], TRUE);
```

I suspect this array `/'.$user.'/pages'` is the error. I'm having lot of trouble with this. might be a simple error.

```
array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/pages'),
```

Comment: What exactly _is_ the error you’re getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try{} using **$user_profile[id]**, also make sure you have perms needed to display this info about a user.

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $_SESSION['fb_APPID_access_token'];
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```